# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=0$ for every $x > 0$. Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$

Tags: limits, continuity

Function $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. For every positive $x$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=0$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$. I have tried to deduce something from definition of continuity, but with no effect.

Comment: What level course is this for? To me this is the kind of question that seems like a Baire Category Theorem thing.

Comment: $n$ is an integer?

Comment: But can you just not rewrite the limit such that $y=\frac{x}{n}$ and so you get what you need by letting $y$ going to 0, which does happen as $n$ goes to infinity and $x$ is any positive real and f is continuous of course so the limit exists?

Comment: @Moya introductory level

Comment: This I believe is just a bit more general than the following, you can proceed in a similar manner https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045776/lim-limits-x-downarrow0-fx-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-f-frac1x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof relies on the following lemma:

Let $I \subset (0,\infty)$ be a closed bounded interval. Let $U \subset (0,\infty)$ be an open subset accumulating at $0$. Then there exists some integer $N \geq 2$ and some closed interval $J \subset U$ such that $N \cdot J \subset I$.

Sketch of proof: take some $x \in U$ with $x$ lower than the length of $I$ and the minimum of $I$ . For some integer $N \geq 2$, $Nx \in \overset{\circ}{I}$, thus, there exists some compact interval $J \subset U$ such that $N \cdot J \subset I$.

Now, assume $f$ does not go to $0$ at $0$. Then, for some $\epsilon > 0$, $U=\{|f| > \epsilon\}$ is an open subset of $(0,\infty)$ accumulating at $0$.

By iterating the lemma, we can construct sequences of compact intervals $(I_n)$ and integers $(N_n)$ such that $N_{n+1}I_{n+1} \subset I_{n-1}$, $N_n \geq 2$.

Now, let $A_n=N_1 \ldots N_n$, then $A_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $K_n=A_n \cdot I_n$ is a non-increasing sequence of nonempty compact intervals in $I_0$. Thus, there exists $x$ that is in every $K_n$.

So, $x/A_n \in I_n \subset U$, for all $n$, thus $|f(x/A_n)| > \epsilon$ for all $n$, a contradiction.

Comment: (edited) This looks correct, but I think you can remove some of the intermediate claims without affecting the argument. In particular, you don't need any information about $\sup I_n$. Also, when you say the sequence $K_n$ is non-decreasing, I think you mean that it *is* decreasing, or in more familiar language, descending. And in the final sentence, "all $n$" should be "infinitely many $n$".

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, I edited. However, in the last sentence, I definitely meant « for all $n$ » and not « for infinitely many $n$», however this does not affect the result.

Comment: Reminds me of the Axiom of Archimedes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard application of Baire Category Theorem (BCT). Since $(0,\infty)=\cup_n \{x:|f(\frac x k)| \leq\epsilon \,\forall k \leq n\}$ there exists $n$ such that $\{x:|f(\frac x k)| \leq \epsilon \, \forall k \geq n\}$ contains some open interval $(a,b)$. [ Because $(0,\infty)$, being an open subset of $\mathbb R$ has an equivalent complete metric so BCT applies]. This gives UNIFORM convergence of $f(\frac x n)$ to $0$ on some open interval from which the result follows easily. [ Details: let $0<\delta <b-a$ and $\delta < \frac a n$. Then, for any $x <\delta $ the interval $(\frac a x,\frac b x)$ has length exceeding $1$, so it contains an interger $k$. Hence $kx \in (a,b)$. Also, $k >\frac  a x > \frac a {\delta} > n$ so $|f(x)|=|f(\frac {kx} k)| <\epsilon$].

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $\bigcup_n\{x,\,\forall k\geq n,\, |f(x/k)| \leq \epsilon\}$?

Comment: @Mindlack You are right. That was  a silly mistake I made.