# Suppose $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(\frac{x}{n})=0$ $\forall x \in (0,1)$ then...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:(0,1)\to \Bbb R$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(\frac{x}{n})=0$ $\forall x \in (0,1)$

​1)  Can we  conclude  that  ​$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$   ?

2. what happens if $f$ is continous on $(0,1)$  ?

I succeeded in finding a counterexample for the first question:

we can define the function  $f$ as following  $f(x)=1$   if $\exists p $ such that $p$ is prime and   $x=\frac{1}{p}$ .
we put  $f(x)=0$ otherwise

What about the second question?

Comment: As regards 2) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065572/lim-limits-n-to-inftyf-left-fracxn-right-0-for-every-x-0-prove?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm going to look at it